# Apache Echarts using different dataset formats to achieve the same chart

Tags: javascript, echarts

from:
https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/

It generates two charts from the same dataset:

```js
    source: [
        ['product', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
        ['Matcha Latte', 41.1, 30.4, 65.1, 53.3],
        ['Milk Tea', 86.5, 92.1, 85.7, 83.1],
        ['Cheese Cocoa', 24.1, 67.2, 79.5, 86.4]
    ]
```

and generates:
[image]

from:
[echarts dataset](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/)

I can use a dataset source in a different format:

```js
    source: [
        { product: 'Matcha Latte', count: 823, score: 95.8 },
        { product: 'Milk Tea', count: 235, score: 81.4 },
        { product: 'Cheese Cocoa', count: 1042, score: 91.2 },
        { product: 'Walnut Brownie', count: 988, score: 76.9 }
    ]
```

So, using the different examples, I feel I should be able to generate the same two charts in the image using the dataset like:

```
    source: [
        {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2012', 'value': 41.1},
        {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2013', 'value': 30.4},
        {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2014', 'value': 65.1},
        {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2015', 'value': 53.3},
        {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2012', 'value': 86.5},
        {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2013', 'value': 92.1},
        {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2014', 'value': 85.7},
        {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2015', 'value': 83.1},
        {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2012', 'value': 24.1},
        {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2013', 'value': 67.2},
        {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2014', 'value': 79.5},
        {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2015', 'value': 86.4}
    ]
```

But cannot figure out how.

Yes, I 'can' remap the dataset into the array format used in the original example but think it should be much easier using native echart options

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### Echart's example source

```
source: [
  ['product', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
  ['Matcha Latte', 41.1, 30.4, 65.1, 53.3],
  ['Milk Tea', 86.5, 92.1, 85.7, 83.1],
  ['Cheese Cocoa', 24.1, 67.2, 79.5, 86.4]
]
```

If you observe, we actually passed a matrix table to the source. Where the 'product' is actually the irrelevant intersection of X (year) and Y (name) headers. Here, each intersection of X and Y receives a common value, which I could appropriately draw on paper with logical reasoning.

This can also work because the X-axis of the two diagrams is of "category" type, which allows for the interpretation of this matrix. Please refer to the [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.type).

> 'category' --> Category axis, suitable for discrete category data. Category data can be auto retrieved from series.data or dataset.source, or can be specified via xAxis.data.

#### Solution

Actually, it's simpler than we might think. The necessary matrix can be created from the values you provided. See my example below.

```js
const data = [
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2012', 'value': 41.1},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2013', 'value': 30.4},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2014', 'value': 65.1},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2015', 'value': 53.3},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2012', 'value': 86.5},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2013', 'value': 92.1},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2014', 'value': 85.7},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2015', 'value': 83.1},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2012', 'value': 24.1},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2013', 'value': 67.2},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2014', 'value': 79.5},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2015', 'value': 86.4}
]

// Determine the X and Y headers first
const xHeaders = Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => item.year)));
const yHeaders = Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => item.product)))

// Create the matrix and set the first row as headers
const matrix = [ ['product', ...xHeaders] ]

// Add data to the matrix
yHeaders.forEach(product => {
  const row = [product]
  xHeaders.forEach(year => {
    const value = data.find(item => item.product === product && item.year === year).value
    row.push(value)
  });
  matrix.push(row)
});

console.log(matrix)
```

If we implement this into a function and pass it to the `source`, our diagram will start working right away.

```js
/**
 ** Function: Matrix Generator
 */
const getMatrix = (array, xHeaderName, yHeaderName) => {
  // Determine the X and Y headers first
  const xHeaders = Array.from(new Set(array.map(item => item[xHeaderName])))
  const yHeaders = Array.from(new Set(array.map(item => item[yHeaderName])))

  // Create the matrix and set the first row as headers
  const matrix = [ [yHeaderName, ...xHeaders] ]

  // Add data to the matrix
  yHeaders.forEach(yHeader => {
    const row = [yHeader]
    xHeaders.forEach(xHeader => {
      const value = data.find(item => item[yHeaderName] === yHeader && item[xHeaderName] === xHeader).value
      row.push(value)
    })
    matrix.push(row)
  })
  
  return matrix
}

/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom)

/**
 ** Data
 */
const data = [
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2012', 'value': 41.1},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2013', 'value': 30.4},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2014', 'value': 65.1},
  {'product': 'Matcha Latte', 'year': '2015', 'value': 53.3},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2012', 'value': 86.5},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2013', 'value': 92.1},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2014', 'value': 85.7},
  {'product': 'Milk Tea', 'year': '2015', 'value': 83.1},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2012', 'value': 24.1},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2013', 'value': 67.2},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2014', 'value': 79.5},
  {'product': 'Cheese Cocoa', 'year': '2015', 'value': 86.4}
]

/**
 ** Option
 */
option = {
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {},
  dataset: {
    source: getMatrix(data, 'year', 'product')
  },
  xAxis: [
    { type: 'category', gridIndex: 0 },
    { type: 'category', gridIndex: 1 }
  ],
  yAxis: [{ gridIndex: 0 }, { gridIndex: 1 }],
  grid: [{ bottom: '55%' }, { top: '55%' }],
  series: [
    // These series are in the first grid.
    { type: 'bar', seriesLayoutBy: 'row' },
    { type: 'bar', seriesLayoutBy: 'row' },
    { type: 'bar', seriesLayoutBy: 'row' },
    // These series are in the second grid.
    { type: 'bar', xAxisIndex: 1, yAxisIndex: 1 },
    { type: 'bar', xAxisIndex: 1, yAxisIndex: 1 },
    { type: 'bar', xAxisIndex: 1, yAxisIndex: 1 },
    { type: 'bar', xAxisIndex: 1, yAxisIndex: 1 }
  ]
}

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but as I mentioned in the original question:
Yes, I 'can' remap the dataset into the array format used in the original...

I'm trying to do it without remapping the dataset I have without forcing it into the dataset used in the example.

I feel transforming the data in the dataset is an easy out.

Seems very odd to me that ECharts gives me at least 4 ways to define a dataset with dimensions BUT doesn't allow me to treat those 4 ways as interchangeable without transforming them between different charts.

Comment: If you don't perform the transformation yourself and instead rely on ECharts to provide this capability, the end result remains unchanged. The transformation of the dataset can be done in various ways, and I believe it doesn't burden the client because ECharts could perform the same operation in the background. The example I provided is just one among many possibilities, and you can use multiple datasets, stacked bars, and more. The manipulation is left to the developer's discretion.

Comment: ECharts might transform one dataset format into another in the background.  I'm not going to walk their code to figure out and I'm not wanting to speculate.

I'm just wanting to produce the chart above using a different, allowed, dataset format without doing my own transformation to match the dataset format in the example.

Can you help with that?